# GetOpenFileName Program-Defined Directory

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a dialog box that resembles the one created with GetOpenFileDialog. However, I want the dialog to display a list of filenames that the program provides, and these filenames don't necessarily exist as files in a directory. The purpose is to provide a dialog with a similar look and feel for opening files, but rather inside of a zip file which the program would extract after selection. So, is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to write one yourself. You can however find the common dialog box templates in the `PlatformSDK\Include` directory; you can use the `FileOpen.dlg` template to build a dialog similar to the standard Open dialog.